# I want to change the text on a button 5 times when I click on it

Tags: javascript

```
function click(){
    if(document.getElementByID("Buttonname").value=="Created")
        document.getElementByID("Buttonname").value="Open"
}
```

I am using this code but it's not working properly. Please suggest.

Comment: @Danny Beckett 's answer seems to resolve the issue with your code, but I am confused by the "5 times" in your question. Are you expecting this to do more than one thing in sequence, or to apply to multiple buttons?

Comment: You have also missed to type a semicolon after `document.getElementByID("Buttonname").value="Open"` Although the parser will add one in this case, it is not a good practice, however.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. `getElementByID` should read `getElementById`.

JavaScript is case-sensitive.

So:

```
function click(){
    if(document.getElementById("Buttonname").value=="Created")
        document.getElementById("Buttonname").value="Open"
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVvDt/).

Answer (score 1):

Change your function name from click to any other name,

```
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Created" onclick="Myclick()" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function Myclick() {
      if (document.getElementById("btn").value == "Created")
          document.getElementById("btn").value = "Open"

   }
```